# PHP Header('Location: XYZ'); to locate to a div

Tags: php, html, css

going to keep this short!
So I've got a login/registration page and when a user registers to the site I want them to be shown the login page. Please note it's ONE page with the login and registration side by side, and when one is clicked it's shown whilst the other one is hidden.

Here is the page -index:
http://prntscr.com/ci48ee - What it looks like upon loading.
Here is the page -index upon clicking the login bit:
http://prntscr.com/ci48jh

index code:

```
<?php
include 'dbh.php';
if(isset($_POST['rsubmit'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$plainpass = $_POST['password'];
$password = password_hash($plainpass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 10));
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
header('Location: #login');
}else {}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Mr. Liam</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="form"> 
      <ul class="tab-group">
        <li class="tab active"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#login">Log In</a></li>
      </ul>     
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="signup">   
          <h1>Sign Up to view content</h1>          
          <form action="index.php" method="post">          
          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Username<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input name="username" type="text"required/>
          </div> 
          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input name="email" type="email"required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>          
          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Set A Password<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input name="password" type="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>         
          <button name="rsubmit" type="submit" class="button button-block"/>Register</button>         
          </form>
        </div>        
        <div id="login">   
          <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>         
          <form action="/" method="post">          
            <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="email"required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>          
          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Password<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>         
          <p class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>          
          <button class="button button-block"/>Log In</button>          
          </form>
        </div>        
      </div><!-- tab-content -->      
</div> <!-- /form -->
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>  
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm guessing it's something along the lines of this??

```
Header('Location: #login');
```

But when I tried that it doesn't work. If you need any more info let me know!

Comment: Post your php code to be able to help!

Comment: `Header("Location: [...]")` is generally to forward to a different page. You're thinking of anchor tags, perhaps?

Comment: lighshots-links not available... better to include screenshots here!

Comment: Need the php code to be certain about what you're doing but header('Location: http://www.example.com/#login'); is what might do the trick.

Comment: @YazanWYusuf I'll update OP with PHP also now.

Comment: @Rabby I've added it now :)

Comment: *" it doesn't work"* is not a proper problem description. What happens? Do you have any javascript code to switch the  tabs based on the hash?

Comment: @LewisHoggerson did you try with the full url as in header('Location: example.com/#login')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change which tab is active by setting the active class to the appropriate tab.

Currently it is on the signup tab and therefor that will be the tab that will load by default. I changed it below.

```
      <ul class="tab-group">
        <li class="tab"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li class="tab active"><a href="#login">Log In</a></li>
      </ul>
```

If you want to do this dynamically you can do..

```
<?php
$currentPage = $_GET['page'];
?>

      <ul class="tab-group">
        <li class="tab <?php if ($currentPage == "signup" ){echo "active" } ?>"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li class="tab <?php if ($currentPage == "login" ){echo "active" } ?>"><a href="#login">Log In</a></li>
      </ul>
```

So if the user goes to

> www.website.com/user?page=login

if will show the login tab. or if they go to

> www.website.com/user?page=signup

it will show the register tab.

Comment: @LewisHoggerson Sorry I just realized. I updated my answer. Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there Lewis. The only thing to note with `header("Location: [...]");` and using an anchor like `#login`, is that it's going to try and find `<.... id="login">` and scroll to that. It doesn't do what you want without slight modification within jQuery.

```
var allowed = ['#signup', '#login'];
if (!empty(window.location.hash)) {
    var action = window.location.hash;
    // check if in our array
    if(jQuery.inArray(action, allowed)) {
        jQuery('a[href=' + action + ']').trigger('click');
    }
}
```

<sup>*I've just made a white list above (`var allowed = ...`). Just to keep it from any unwanted use.*</sup>

If you're using Bootstrap, it usually takes care of the above itself.

---

One thing to note about `header()` is that you need a qualified location to redirect to. So `header("Location: yourwebsite.com/#login");` would be more adequate.